# Insert values from 2 maps<int, vector<char>> into 1 map<vector<char>, vector<char>>

Tags: c++

I have

map<int,vector> x {1,a}{2,b}{3,c}

map<int,vector> y {1,x}{2,y}{3,z}

map<vector, vector> newMap

I want to the values of x.second and y.second into

newMap<x.second, y.second>

I want to get {a,x}{b,y}{c,z}

```
map<int, vector<char>>* phrasex;
map<int, vector<char>>* encodedx;
map<char, char>* mapCharacters = new map<char, char>;
auto it1 = encodedx->begin();
auto it2 = phrasex->begin();

    while (it1 != encodedx->end())
    {
        auto t1 = it1->second.begin();
        while (t1 != it1->second.end()) {
            //i'm doing something wrong here
            mapCharacters->insert({ {it1->second},{it2->second} });
            //
        }
        
        ++it1;
        ++it2;
    }
```

Comment: how about `for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) newMap.insert({x[i].second, y[i].second});`?

Comment: I would suggest the two-input-iterator overload of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) together with [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) and a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Maybe a little more to write than the solution by @mch, but more generic. And definitely more "C++-ish" (which might, or might not, be a good thing) :)

Comment: You've described what you want, what is your specific C++ question? We don't write code for other people here, we only answer questions. Please see [ask] questions.

Comment: I am not sure how to phrase the question so I thought the best way was to just say what I need. Thanks for the link, I'm using auto it to loop through the 2 maps but I'm still stuck trying to reference and loop the 2 vectors in newMap at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform(
    std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(y),
    std::inserter(newMap, std::end(newMap)),
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return std::make_pair(lhs.second, rhs.second);
    });
```

Note that this requires C++14 because of auto parameters in the lambda function. In C++11 you would have to write the type `std::pair<int, std::vector<char>>` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
typedef vector<char> vchar;
typedef map<int, vchar>   map_vchar;
typedef map<vchar, vchar> map_vch;
typedef pair<int, vchar>  pr_vchar;

int main() {
    vchar     vc1a(10, 'a');
    vchar     vc2a(10, 'b');
    map_vchar m1 { {1, vc1a}, {2, vc2a} };

    vchar     vc1b(10, 'a');
    vchar     vc2b(10, 'b');
    map_vchar m2 { {1, vc1b}, {1, vc2b} };

    map_vch combined;

    transform(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), inserter(combined, combined.end()),
        [] (const pr_vchar& pr1, const pr_vchar& pr2) {
            return pair<vchar, vchar>{pr1.second, pr2.second};
        ;}
    );

    return 0;
}
```

I can't be certain, but it appears that the original choice for `map<int, vector<char>>` could be better substituted with `vector<char>`, and maybe even a `string`.

Comment: Thank you, i've tried so many different things!

Answer (score 0):

```
    map<vector<char>, vector<char>>* mapCharacters = new map<vector<char>, vector<char>>;
    map<int, vector<char>>* phrasex;
    map<int, vector<char>>* encodedx;

    for (map<int, vector<char>>::iterator i = encodedx->begin(), j = phrasex->begin(); i != encodedx->end(), j != phrasex->end(); ++i, ++j)
    {
        for (vector<char>::iterator x = i->second.begin(), y = j->second.begin(); x != i->second.end(), y != j->second.end(); ++x, ++y) {
            
            mapCharacters->insert({ {*x},{*y} });
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Be very careful using the comma operator `,` in the for-loop terminating clause (the second clause) like you're doing. In fact just don't use it, unless you really understand it, because it's a source of frequent bugs even for experienced C++ programmers. I'm certain you actually mean to use `&&` instead.